# Can I use a link_to to generate a link with a span inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, href, link-to

I am basically trying to get this result:

```
        <a href="#" class="button small-button green-button">
            Log in
            <span class="button-right"></span>
        </a>
```

But I don't know how to do this with a link_to in rails 3 ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the block form of `link_to` for that:

```
<%= link_to "#", :class => "button small-button green-button" do %>
  Log in
  <span class="button-right"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do it is by using **html_safe** or **raw** functions

```
<%= link_to 'Log In<span class="button-right"></span>'.html_safe %>
```

or using raw function (recommended)

```
<%= link_to raw('Log In<span class="button-right"></span>') %>
```

Simple as it can get !!

Don’t use **html_safe** method unless you’re sure your string isn’t nil. Instead use the raw() method, which wont raise an exception on nil.

Answer (score 3):

Your snippet looks like a static link, that will never change when interpreted by Rails; I suppose its save to insert the raw HTML in your view.

However:

```
<%= link_to("#", :class=>"button small-button green-button") do %>
  Log in
  <span class="button-right"></span>
<% end %>
```

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me. I don't know why other pieces of code didn't (different ruby version?).

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'Register'), {:action => "register"}, :class=>"button" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jeremy's answer - for a path, like so:

```
          <%= link_to edit_section_path(@section) do %>
              Edit
              <span class="fa fa-list pull-right"></span>
          <% end %>
```