# Using jQuery.html method to set a Div to a Rails link_to with a span

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

NOTE: this is within a *.js.erb file

I am having trouble using the jQuery $.html() method to edit a div.  Particularly, I want to edit a div to create a link_to span within the div (that includes rails injection).  My issue is that this is usually accomplished with multiple ruby-injected lines and I'm having issues doing this within the parameters of the .html() method.

I looked here: 
[Can I use a link_to to generate a link with a span inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837824/can-i-use-a-link-to-to-generate-a-link-with-a-span-inside)

(this is the normal way to create a link_to span however I'm not sure how to do this within the context of the jQuery.html method

& also

[Multiple lines when using jQuery's .html method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676990/multiple-lines-when-using-jquerys-html-method)

(tried this in conjunction with the above posted solution, didn't work)

-I also tried to use link_to "stuff here with <% ruby code %> ".html_safe and it would not work.

TLDR: how do I recreate an instance of the div below ("schedule_call_#") using a single jQuery.html call

```
<td id="schedule_call_<%= c.id %>" class="scheduled-cell">
                <%= link_to show_scheduled_events_crm_client_path(c), :remote => true do %>
                    <span class="ui blue small icon button scheduled-count schedule-button leads">
                      <%= c.count_scheduled_events(true) %>
                    </span>
                <% end %>
</td>
```

meaning i want something like  $(div).html(STUFF HERE) and STUFF HERE is the code section above.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking. `.html()` just sets the inner HTML of an element, so you just pass that completed HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not have access to your ruby variables or parameters in js so **you should use [`html5 data attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on element which will fire your js**. In your case lets say its a link, so you can do

```
<%= link_to "xyz", xyz_path, class: "sample_link", data: {id: c.id, href: show_scheduled_events_crm_client_path(c), count: c.count_scheduled_events(true) } %>
```

Now write js method which will fire on click of this link

```
$(document).on("click",".sample_link",function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var href = $(this).data("href");
  var count = $(this).data("count");
  var element = "<a href='" +href+ "' data-remote=true><span class='ui blue small icon button scheduled-count schedule-button leads'>" +count+ "</span></a>";
  $("#schedule_call_"+id).html(element);
});
```