# how to use link with glyphicon rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the same effect as this

```
                <div id='async_btn',  class="btn" href="#modal-container-340088"  data-toggle="modal"><%= image_tag "msg.jpg" %></div>
```

but with a glyphicon envelope. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>'.html_safe, { :id => 'async_btn', :class => 'btn', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#modal-container-340088'} %>
```

but it doesn't work- ie modal not rendered

Comment: I think this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4837865/771578

Comment: The problem is more to do with the fact that the modal is not being shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code with `link_to ... .html_safe` is rendering a wrong `href` attribute. This can prevent the modal window appear.

You can use just html:

```html
<a href='#' id="async_btn" class="btn" data-target="#modal-container-340088"  data-toggle="modal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" />
</a>
```

But if you really need to use erb, try this:

```ruby
<%= link_to "#", { :id => 'async_btn', :class => 'btn', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#modal-container-340088'} do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" />
<% end %>
```